# Firebase C++ SDK Multithreaded DLL /MD has no DLL files, Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, firebase

On Firebase CPP SDK website, it states:

> For Windows, library versions are provided based on the following:
>
> Build platform: 32-bit (x86) vs 64-bit (x64) mode
>
> Windows runtime environment: Multithreaded / MT vs Multithreaded DLL
> /MD
>
> Target: Release vs Debug

But the build they have provided have no DLL files, and only Lib files, when i link the Lib files, the project works fine, how is it possible that it does not ask for firebase DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Donnot need dll at run time when link to a static library.

Here is what I found :

[enter link description here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/)

> A static library (also known as an archive) consists of routines that are compiled and linked directly into your program. When you compile a program that uses a static library, all the functionality of the static library that your program uses becomes part of your executable. On Windows, static libraries typically have a .lib extension, whereas on linux, static libraries typically have an .a (archive) extension. One advantage of static libraries is that you only have to distribute the executable in order for users to run your program. Because the library becomes part of your program, this ensures that the right version of the library is always used with your program. Also, because static libraries become part of your program, you can use them just like functionality you’ve written for your own program. On the downside, because a copy of the library becomes part of every executable that uses it, this can cause a lot of wasted space. Static libraries also can not be upgraded easy -- to update the library, the entire executable needs to be replaced.